# How to get the user to change the background color of a JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jtextarea

I am coding a basic text editor and i want to give the user the option to change the background color. Right it can only be changed to red, here's my code snippet.

```
private void MiColorActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
     jTextArea2.setSize(350, 350);
     jTextArea2.setVisible(true);
     jTextArea2.setBackground(Color.red);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a JFrame or a JPanel, which is what I use when working JTextFields. You can then later on add the text field on the frame, with frame.add(textField).